# Access mysql DB from different instance on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have 2 instances in EC2 server, one instance has the mysql DB and the content stored in it and another instance to access the data stored in the first instance.

I need to create a user with read only access stored in the Database.

So

1. `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

   `grant select on DBname.* to 'chowzter'@'localhost';`

**ERROR**

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

2 . `CREATE USER 'username'@'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

`grant select on DBname.* to 'username'@'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com';`

This time the ip address used was the internal IP of the `second instance` got by the command.

`ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 12:31:41:02:58:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet **XX.XX.XX.XXX/23** brd YY.YYY.YY.YYY scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::1031:41ff:fe02:5847/64 scope link 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip address: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX/23"

command: `mysql -hxx.xx.xxx.xxx -uusername -ppassword`

**ERROR**

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)
```

Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you running in a VPC?

Comment: No its not VPC but AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it .

First I created a user by using `%`.

```
 CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then you can give privileges to that user.

```
grant select on DBname.* to 'name'@'%';

mysql -h xx.xx.xxx.xxx -u user -p
```

That gives me the privilege to access the DB in Read only mode from second instance..

Comment: '%'  gives access to the said user from any IP  which makes the complete system insecure.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your grant up for any host. But control access via granting permissions to the security group. Internal IPs can change if an instance is stopped/restarted.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to the mysql instance from a different instance you should do the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBname.* TO 'chowzter'@'xx.xx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON facebook.* TO 'zuckerberg'@'10.0.0.420' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecuredpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can go through MySql Documentation to under this even better:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

This should pretty much work assuming firewall allow access within VPC and you dont have bind address enabled.